Limits by Products and equalizers Mac Lane book cwm
On The Page 113 the Third line below diagram (1), I do not Follow the equation $F_u\mu_j=\mu_k$

Hi and welcome to MSE! Please make this question mostly self-contained. Nobody wants to or can pick up that book (which would probably have to be exactly your edition, too) just to make sense of your question.

@BenSteffan I would Love to but I am writing from my mobile phone from Prison with the book lying on the table

We have $$ \begin{align}F_u \circ \mu_j &= F_u \circ p_j \circ e \\ &= p_u \circ g \circ e \\ &= p_u \circ f \circ e \\ &= p_k \circ e \\ &= \mu_k\end{align}$$ where all the equations follow from the commutativity of diagram (1).
If you'd like to see a formalised proof, check out the 1Lab (click "read more" and look at the definition of lim .commutes).
